# how to solve this error in c type conversion?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, type-conversion, unsigned

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned char uint8;
int main()
{
    double a = 1320.134;
    uint32 b;
    uint8 c[20];
     b = (unsigned int)a;
    c[3] = b;      //c[3] = (unsigned char)b;
    printf("value of %c", c[3]);
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to do some type conversion in my program. Inside the main function- 1: I am converting and store it in a double. 2: I want to store the uint32 value in a character array at third position but I am not able to get the output, if I do as above. Please someone help me on this ??

output: value of c <.  //some junk value 
how to read the 1320 in c[3] ?

Answer (score 3):

> how to read the `1320` in `c[3]`

There is mathematically no way to read anything larger than 255 from a single `unsigned char`. The value that you see, 40 (0x28, which represents an opening parenthesis character) is the last eight bits of the 1320 - a result of truncation of 0x528.

Comment: thank you and one more question : instead of typedef unsigned char , I will make it as typedef unsigned int uint8 c[]; then it will be of 1byte size. isnt it ??

Comment: @user3458454 `char` and `unsigned char` are one byte (C standard actually requires that). If you typedef `unsigned int`, you would get at least two bytes per element of `c[]` array; on most modern systems you'd get four bytes per element of the array.

Comment: is there any way to store my results in character array ??

Comment: @user3458454 In a character array - yes, of course, but not in a single element of a character array, because the number that you wish to store has 11 bits, so it does not fit in an eight-bit byte. You need at least two eight-bit elements to store the 1320 number.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
printf("value of %d", c[3]);
```

instead of

```
printf("value of %c", c[3]);
```

in addition, and 8-bit unsigned integer can be as high as 255. the over part will be cut-off.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill actually, compiler will fetch the last 8 bits from memory(register) and assign it to c[3].

Comment: thank you and one more question : instead of typedef unsigned char , I will make it as typedef unsigned int uint8 c[]; then it will be of 1byte size. isnt it ??

Comment: @user3458454 you can use `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(uint8)` to see how many bytes they are.

Comment: if I give like this : printf("value of %d", c[3]); then I am getting 40 as the output :(

Comment: @user3458454 of course. a byte can't store a 1320, it can store as high as 255.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the overview of what is happening:

First you set: `uint32 b = (unsigned int)(1320.134)` which just makes it `b = 1320`.

1320 is a number that is more that 8 bits so it won't just fit into the 8 bit space (`c[3]`), so instead it forces it in there and ignores the leftover bits, so instead you get 1320%256 (the % means remainder after division), which happens to be 40. Now, this number, when converted into ascii character form, is then printed out.

REVISION:

So from what I understand, you want there to be some overflow into the next element, so you need to do some complicated pointer work. Here is how I would go about it.

```
uint32 b = 1320;
uint8 c[20];

//first, get a pointer to the 3rd array element, and convert it to a uint32 pointer:
uint32 *pointer = &c[3];
//now, lets dereference it and put the value into the location:
*pointer = b;
```

This should give the proper overflow, but im very curious, what could you possibly want to do this for?

Here is how it gets stored by the way:

```
| | | |40|5 | ...
```

The reason for this is that the binary representation of 1320 is 10100101000. This is stored backwards in the memory, and the bits end up being placed like this:

```
| | | |00010100|10100000|
```

and when read (backwards), 00010100 is equal to 40 and 10100000 is equal to 5

Comment: is there any way to store my results in character array ??

Comment: do you want an overflow into the next array element?

Comment: how to store it in a next array element ??

Comment: lets say that a number is three digits long and each array element could only hold 2. Would you want inserting 123 into the first element to be `12| |` or `12|3 |`?

Comment: to store the element to be 12|3|

Comment: Here you need to do some complicated pointer work, ill revise this answer